# Custom Form in Visual Studio and Approval workflow

Tags: 2010, workflow, visual-studio, visual-web-part

I have developed a form in Visual Studio 2010 professional as Visual WebPart in which I have the following fields and for the same I have created a LIST with the same columns.

1. Employee ID
2. Employee Name
3. Login ID
4. Internet Access Required  Yes  No  (Radio Buttons)
5. ID   Create...Reset...Delete   (CheckBoxes for these 3 selections)
6. Unit Head Approval
7. Department Head Approval

Actually user will fill the fields from 1 to 5 and upon submission I want Unit Head to approve the request and then it should go to Department Head for approval.

I am unable understand how to do this so please help me connecting the dots ...and guide me what steps are required to achieve this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand why do you craete your custom form? Do you want to use this form as workflow initial form? if so, you can see [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc160835.aspx#WSS_AccessDataFromWorkflow_AddFormsCode). Also you can see [this video](http://www.sheltonblog.com/archive/2007/11/21/how-to-video-building-a-basic-approval-workflow-with-sharepoint.aspx) to understant how to create simple approval workflow.

Comment: Because we have standard license and can't design and publish infopath form that's why. What do you suggest Alexander? let me know if I can simplify things on your advise

Comment: Well while I've posted the question here I did create the same form using OOTB and called the list using SharePoint Controls in Designer..and called the Custom List Form and defined the Type. Fine but how to attach the approval process for UNIT HEADS and DEPARTMENT HEAD using both Scenarios...with/without Visual Studio Custom Form.

Comment: I do not know your task. But I see following solution. You can create list with these fields. when the user clicks "Add new item" link on list view form of this list, the create new item form is opened (it is auto generated form, I think that you do not need licence for this :) ). The user fills this form and click create. After this your workflow is started. In workflow you can retrieve data from this item. in other case you can see post that I provided. it describes how to create initialization form for workflow. but in this case you can see this form only if the user starts workflow manual.

Comment: also you can create list, each item of this list should contains user, unit head and department head names. In your workflow you can get an item that is relevant to you user and retrive approvers names.

Comment: The task is simple Alexander...we are IT department and we receive forms from users for different purpose like MIS Report Request Form, Leave Application Form etc. Every department has UNIT HEADS and DEPARTMENT HEAD ..upon submission I want the automatic process of approval from bottom to top like first unit head approval and finally head of department and whenever approver approves the form field where it says UNIT HEAD and HEAD OF DEPARTMENT the name should appear with the status "Approved" with the current date. I've developed the form based on ur advise just need to work on workflow part.

Comment: the common scenario for approval workflow is to create a task and notify parson which task is assigned. See video how to implement it.

Comment: Alexander I just figured this out and I am receiving emails for the task and did approved :) But cant I have "Approved" status infront of the Form Field instead of Two "Approved" items in LIST ITEM?

Comment: Basically the developers create a choice field in the list (Not started, In progress, Approved, Rejected). this field is changed by a workflow, if i'm not wrong there is an activity in VS2010.

Comment: well ok let me accept your answer..and in the mean time I will figure out the rest. Thank you so much for guiding me in right direction..learned a lot from you today.